# Каким способом лучше хранить пароль от базы данных?

Tags: php

Каким способом лучше хранить пароль от базы данных?

Comment: в папке, где находиться на один уровень вверх от корневой папки

Answer (score 3):

Короче, перейдите на один уровен вверх от корневого каталога, 
и там создаете конфигурационный файл, в нем храните секретные 
данные от посторонних глаз.
А подключаете как обычно `includ - ом(include './conf.php';)`
Хаккер не сможет туда попасть, если <s>у него не будеть фонарика )))</s>  даже он все таки взломает <s>вас</s> ваш сайт .

Answer (score 2):

[E-Token](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/EToken)

> eToken (от англ. electronic — электронный и англ. token — признак, жетон) — торговая марка для линейки персональных средств аутентификации в виде USB-брелоков и смарткарт, а также программные решения с их использованием.

А если Вы спрашиваете о том, как хранить конфигурационные данные о подключении к БД, то используйте, наприме ini-файлы. Запретить доступ к ним, вне сервера, можно с помощью прописывания в .htaccess:

```
<Files ~ "\.ini$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: @stck, да, автор смутно "описал" проблему. Мне тоже непонятно какой пароль, и где именно лежит, и от кого собственно защитить...Благодаря по телепатическому способности я решил это некое конфигурационный файл бд.

Comment: Пример кода:

    $server_db = "localhost";
    $login_db = "пользователь базы данных";
    $pass_db = "пароль к базе данных";
    $datebase_db = "база данных";

    mysql_connect ($server_db,$login_db,$pass_db) or die('Оши6ка!');
    mysql_select_db ($datebase_db) or die('Оши6ка!');

Если хакер каким то образом получить доступ к php коду, он не сможет узнать пароль от базы данных. Как это реализовать?

Просто разработчики php допустили ошибку (http://www.xakep.ru/post/59267/), но конечно они эту ошибку исправили, но вдруг такое ещё повторится =(

Comment: @Riolu, как раз об этом и написал я.(+_+)

Comment: @Riolu, подойдём к этому с другой стороны. Создайте пользователя с правами только на чтение. Используйте его. Даже если будет получен доступ к коду, к паролю от базы - кроме того, что скачать, он не получит никакого доступа. Файл Ваш, не зайдя на сервер и так никто открыть не сможет - прогонится через PHP, но вывода не последует. А вот если у него будет доступ к серверу - то тут Вы уже ничего не поделаете